# Delete specific rows based on specific word in column

Tags: bash, csv

I have very large tab-separated files, and I need delete all rows where the word "TelePacific" appears in a specific column.  In this case all the rows where TelePacifc occurs in the 4th column.  Here is an example input file:

```
7/18/13 10:06   0:00:09 TelePacific random person DEREK         9256408665  random company
7/18/13 10:07   0:00:21 TelePacific random person DEREK         9256408665  random company
7/18/13 10:10   0:19:21 TelePacific random person DEREK         9256408665  random company
7/18/13 10:39   0:01:07 random person       107  
7/18/13 11:02   0:01:41 random person Gilbert       107 TelePacific
7/18/13 12:17   0:00:42 random person Gilbert       107 TelePacific
7/18/13 13:35   0:00:41 random person Gilbert       107 TelePacific
7/18/13 13:44   0:12:30 TelePacific ADKNOWLEDGE     8169311771  random company
7/18/13 14:46   0:19:48 TelePacific TOLL FREE CALL  8772933939  random company
7/15/13 10:09   0:01:27 random person Esquivel      272 TelePacific
7/15/13 10:16   0:00:55 random person Esquivel      272 TelePacific
7/15/13 10:59   0:00:51 random person Esquivel      272 TelePacific
7/15/13 11:01   0:01:09 random person Esquivel      272 TelePacific
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `grep -v`:

```
grep -v "\bTelePacific\b" file > output && mv output file
```

Or using awk:

```
awk '$4 != "TelePacific"' file > output && mv output file
```

Comment: +1 for `\b` ("match word boundary"), so you only match the _word_ "TelePacific" instead of "FooTelePacific" or "TelePacificFoo".

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$ sed '/TelePacific/d' file
```

If you are happy with the output use the `-i` option to store the changes back to the file.

```
$ sed -i '/TelePacific/d' file
```

**EDIT:**

To only return results for `TelePacific` in the fourth column:

```
$ awk '$4=="TelePacific"' file
```

Or the inverse:

```
$ awk '$4!="TelePacific"' file
```

Comment: Won't this also delete lines with text `FooTelePacific`?

Comment: Sure it would, but the question wasn't that specific.

Comment: @ahilsend: Example file and this statement `I have very large tab separated files` indicates it is a separate word.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it where it only searches for instances of TelePacific in the 4th column?

Answer (score 1):

`fgrep -v` will do this.

`fgrep` is equivalent to `grep -F` and prevents `grep` from interpreting special characters in your pattern as regex control characters. The `-v` parameter causes `fgrep` to output all lines that *don't* match the pattern, in contrast to outputting the lines that do (which is the default).

```
fgrep -v TelePacific inputfile.tsv > outputfile.tsv
```

As *anubhava* noted above, you may choose `grep -v "\bTelePacific\b"` instead to ensure that you don't accidentally match "TelePacificFoo" or "FooTelePacific".

Comment: Is there anyway to do it where it only searches for instances of TelePacific in the 4th column?

Comment: @Fr0ntSight That's the point where grep-related tools stop being very helpful. You could write a really nasty regular expression to parse tabs, or make a clever loop in shell script, but `awk` is actually designed for whitespace-delimited separated fields and that makes _anubhava_'s `awk` solution the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution with sed

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '/TelePacific/d' your_file.txt > file_without_telepacific.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -v TelePacific in-file > out-file
```

The `-v` option inverts the search, so grep prints all lines that don't match the search pattern.

This won't work if `in-file` and `out-file` are the same. To achive that you have to use a temp file like this:

```
grep -v TelePacific in-file > in-file.tmp && mv in-file.tmp in-file
```